# Jquery fadeTo with toggle nav

Tags: jquery, toggle

**The Problem**

I've got a side navigation that I've put together and so far it's working ok. I'm trying to fade in a little 'close' button on the panel that gets toggled so a user can easily close the toggled panel if they are done with it.

I have something in place that's sort of doing it, but if you click from one side nav item to another, you'll see that it gets messy and out of sync.

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/visualdecree/4A23Z/37/

**jQuery**

```
$(".sn a").on('click',function(){ // Sidenav panel script

    var panID = $("#" + $(this).data('panel') );

    $("div[id*='sn-pan-']")
    .stop()
    .hide({slide:'toggle'}, 400);

    $(panID)
    .css({'left' : '139px','overflow':'visible'})
    .stop()
    .animate({width:'toggle'}, 400)

        $(".control-view").stop().fadeOut("slow");  // Fadein menu close button
    $(".control-view").not(":visible").stop().delay(400).fadeTo("fast", 0.33);   

});

$('.sn').click(function(e) {
    $('ul.sidenav li').not(this).removeClass('active'); // Active class removal / add
    $(this).stop(true, true).toggleClass("active");    
});

$(".control-view").hover( // Hover effect for menu close button
    function () {
    $(".control-view").stop().hide().fadeTo("fast", 1); // Hover in
   }, 
    function () {
    $(".control-view").fadeTo("normal",0.33); // Fade back to previous set opacity
});

$('.control-view').click(function(e) {
        $("div[id*='sn-pan-']")
        .stop()
        .hide({slide:'toggle'}, 400);

        $('ul.sidenav li').not(this).removeClass('active');

        $(".control-view").stop().fadeOut("fast");
});
```

I appreciate my code might be messy, I'm learning so anything you can help with i will appreciate and take away with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line

```
$(".control-view").stop().fadeOut("slow");  // Fadein menu close button
```

To

```
$(".control-view").hide();  // Fadein menu close button
```

Basically the selector

```
$(".control-view").stop().fadeOut("slow");
```

is fading out all the anchors (<a class="control-view"></a>) and then you are immediately trying to find the visible ones with $(".control-view").not(":visible").... but no anchors are actually hidden yet.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation, that makes total sense now. Seems to be working good.

Comment: One thing I've noticed is the animation is not very smooth, is this caused by some problems in my code?

Comment: Which part of the animation are you referring to?